# If else in php does not give a right output

Tags: php

I'm new at PHP so I made my first activity for practice and i can't determine the problem in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>PHP activity</title></head>

<form action="act1.php" method="post"> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit">

</form>
    <?php

 if ($_POST["name"] = " ") {
     echo "Please Enter Your Name!";
 }
else {
echo $_POST["name"];
}
?>
</html>
```

It does not give me my expected output. I was expecting that if the form is blank it must return "Please bla bla" , else , if it's not blank, it will return the input which is name.

But the output is always "Please bla bla"

**I am really new to PHP**

Comment: If yur problem is solved accept the best answer

Answer (score 1):

`=` is for assignment not comparison 
change `if ($_POST["name"] = " ")` to `if ($_POST["name"] == "")`
So your if/else becomes

```
if ($_POST["name"] == "") { 
     echo "Please Enter Your Name!";
 }
else {
echo $_POST["name"];
}
```

Comment: If you did not know about that, then it's fine. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line`if ($_POST["name"] = " ") {`

To this `if ($_POST["name"] == "") {`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used the wrong operator for comparison.

- `=` is used to assign value to a variable. 
  `$x=5;` means the value of `x` has been set to 5.
- `==` is used for comparison.
  `$x==5;` will return true if the the value of `$x` is 5.

Make the correction as shown below:

```
    if ($_POST["name"] ==" ") 
{ 
echo "Please Enter Your Name!"; 
} 
else
 { 
echo $_POST["name"]; 
}
```

Also I think, you are checking if `$_POST["name"]` is null or not in the `if` condition. But your `if block` will only be entered if the value of `$_POST["name"]` is a space. It may not work for multiple spaces and when nothing is entered at all.

You may have to change the condition to:

`if ($_POST["name"] =="\0" || ($_POST["name"] ==" " )`

This again wouldn't work to the expectation if the user enters multiple spaces or special characters.

Note:

`\0` means null character.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using comparison in your example its assigning the value.

One more issue `$var == " "` its not correct it will consider empty space as value `"" != " "`

You can also use `empty()` in your example as:

```
if (empty($_POST["name"])) { 
   echo "Please Enter Your Name!"; 
} else { 
   echo $_POST["name"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your passed some data in POST parameter like below.

```
if (trim($_POST["name"]) == "") {

}
```

**Don't forget to `trim` it to avoid blank character submission.**

You have two mistakes in your code

- You have to check user input using `==` operator instead of `=` operator.
- You are comparing user input with `" "` i.e. blank character which'll be true only when user add one space character in input field.

**NOTE : This condition will be executed every time you visit the page.**

So, you have to check if user pressed `submit` button and then only you have to display error message.

Hope it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

1.change the "name" attribute with "Name" in "text" field
2.add "value" attribute in submit field where value="submit" and change name="Form" in the same
3.Now in your php code check whether form has been submitted if it is submitted
then just check whether there is empty name or not

```
Name:<input type="text" name="Name"/>
     <input type="submit" name="Form" value="submit"/>
<?php
     if($_POST["Form"])
     {
        if ($_POST["Name"]) {
            echo $_POST["Name"];
         }
        else {
             echo "Please Enter Your Name!";   
         }
     }
 ?>
```